# Debugging Strategy for Mysterious Inline Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

for a webapp I'm working with jQueries draggable and droppable function. Everything works fine in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox there is a something weird going on: After dragging an element it gets inline height and width attributes. I already searched my code but can't find the bug.

Is there any way (with devtools for example) to trace back where this particular attributes come from (scripts, browser, ...) and to determine what exactly triggers these mysterious attributes?

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide a working example?

Comment: i could, but i'm not really asking to fix my bug (yet, haha). I'd just like to know if there are tools to trace back these inline-writings.

Comment: sorry, I got excited with the bug. you can search for something like `.attr(` method of jquery or `.setAttribute(` method of javascript in all your JS files as they are used to set attributes. if you're not able to find `width` attribute when its because its a part of some generic code and code can be like `$('ele').attr(someVariableHoldingCSSAttribute, someValue)`.

Comment: Thanks, of course i checked my own code for exactly that. Anyway, found the bug! The Problem was the new version of JqueryUi: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10725 Changed to an older version, now it works flawlessly.